# Не находит файл в папке с проектом

Tags: delphi

По какой-то причине, программа не может найти файл, который находится в папке с самим проектом. Прилагается код программы, а также скрин папки с проектом

```
unit Main;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    StartButton: TButton;
    procedure StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  TWay = record
    F:TextFile;
  end;

const
  n=3;
var
  FormMain: TFormMain;
  MainArray:array[1..n,1..n] of TWay;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormMain.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  j: Integer;
  s:string;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    AssignFile(MainArray[1,i].F,IntToStr(i)+'.txt');
  end;
  Reset(MainArray[1,1].F);
  While not Eof(MainArray[1,1].F) do
  begin
    Readln(MainArray[1,1].F, s);
    Memo1.Text:=Memo1.Text+s;
  end;
end;

end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А при чём тут папка с проектом, если относительный путь - путь относительно exe?

Comment: @zed Это не имеет значения, я могу прописать абсолютный вот так:  'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Аисд лабы 2 сем\Лаба 1'+IntToStr(i)+'.txt' . Результат не изменится

Comment: В вашем примере путь к exe-файлу отличается от пути к проекту, а с абсолютным путём у вас ошибка: `'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Аисд лабы 2 сем\Лаба 1\'`<=== `+ IntToStr(i)+'.txt'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проект по умолчанию собирает EXE не прямо в папку проекта, а в `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)`. В вашем случае, вероятно, это `\Win32\Debug\`. Соответственно никаких `1.txt` там в папке рядом нету. Это видно на вашем скриншоте. Решение - либо поменять папку сборки на `-пусто-`, либо указывать *правильный* относительный путь `..\..\IntToStr(i) + '.txt'` (т.е. подняться на 2 уровня выше).

   *Вот так выглядят настройки проекта по умолчанию:*

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

2. > могу прописать абсолютный вот так:
   > `'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Аисд лабы 2 сем\Лаба 1'+IntToStr(i)+'.txt'`
   > Результат не изменится

Тут очевидно просто ошибка в пути - пропущен слеш после `Лаба 1` и перед именем файла.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в неверном указании пути, был пропущен один обратный слеш перед IntToStr(i)

Comment: И вот тут вместе с ошибкой нужно выводить имя файла, которое мы пытаемся открыть. А вообще абсолютные пути мне не нравятся (хоть это к делу и мало относится).

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, стоило лучше разместить этот файл и прописать относительный путь, благодарю за отзыв! @VladChapl

Comment: Этот ответ не соответствует текущему виду вопроса. Правильный ответ дал рядом.